# USB Keyboard stopped working, but only in Windows - drivers?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers, keyboard

When I plug in my USB Keyboard (Microsoft Comfort Curve 2000), an "Unknown device" shows up in Device Manager:

[click to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdVF8.png)

Occassionaly the keyboard is showed correctly as "Comfort Curve 2000" but still with this yellow triangle. When I uninstall "unknown device" and plug in keyboard, this shows up:

[click to see the screenshot #2](http://i.snag.gy/ItVFy.jpg)

The keyboard was working perfectly before 15 February. During 15-24 February period I didn't use it at all, and today (25 February) it doesn't work. During this time I installed drivers to pciexpress usb 3.0 and a couple of windows updates. I uninstalled them both, but still no luck.

The keyboard works both in BIOS and other computers, so both USB port and the keyboard are fine. I once managed to use it in Windows after restart (not sure how) but it stopped working after a couple of minutes (perhaps it tried to find "better" drivers?).

I don't care if it'll be recognized as Microsoft Keyboard, generic USB keyboard driver would be just fine, but choosing it from drivers list doesn't help.

I tried to remove all keyboard-related devices from Device manager and rebooting.

How would you go about it? Note: I don't have any restore points.

Answer (score 0):

Try un-installing the driver for the keyboard and re-installing them manually. You should be able to find the driver on Microsoft's website. By doing this, you're basically doing a full reset, so if this doesn't work, it may mean that the keyboard or USB port is faulty.

Comment: How do I uninstall the driver? If you mean: to remove any Microsoft-keyboard-related software and click "uninstall" on partially-recognized device in Device Manager, this doesn't help. As I said, the keyboard is working perfectly before Windows boot, so it's a software issue.

Comment: That is correct, and you need to install the corresponding driver too.